# "Главная морфема, без которой невозможно построить слово(,) - корень"

Tags: пунктуация

"Главная морфема, без которой невозможно построить слово, - корень".
Правомерна ли такая постановка знаков препинания?

Comment: Елена, я позволил себе заменить бессодержательный заголовок на то, как японимаю вопрос. Если ошибся, отредактируйте.

Comment: _"Главная морфема, без которой невозможно построить слово..."_ === По-моему, здесь слово "главное" -- лишнее.

Comment: @slava1947 *По-моему, здесь слово "главное" -- лишнее* - 1) почему? O_o 2) автор вопроса не этим интересовался

Comment: _1) почему?_ === Потому что не существует других (неглавных) морфем, "без которых невозможно построить слово..." Можно сказать: _Главная морфема -- корень. Без неё нельзя построить слово._ А вот так , как в вопросе... Ну, может я и ошибаюсь.

Comment: @slava1947 Насчет "другой морфемы" - не ошибаетесь. Но, боюсь, ошибаетесь насчет понимания. *Главная морфема -- корень. Без неё нельзя построить слово* - они это и имели ввиду.  *Столи́ца — главный город государства, местопребывание правительства и других высших органов государственной власти* - не будете спрашивать про "другие" города?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько понимаю, вопрос о запятой перед тире, другие места сомнений по пунктуации не вызывают.

**Знаки в вашем варианте, судя по всему, поставлены верно**. Но очень трудно найти единое и исчерпывающее правило на этот счет. Вопрос о пунктуации на месте стечения тире и запятой, поставленных по разным мотивам ("независимо", как иногда говорят), обсуждался неоднократно, иногда тире "поглощает" запятую, иногда нет, исчерпывающего формального правила или набора таковых я не видел.

На практике здесь обычно руководствуются соображениями о сохранении наглядности структуры. Если запятую опустить (т.е. позволить тире "поглотить" её), то нарушается восприятие границ обособляемой части (в данном случае это вообще придаточное предложение), ведь тире может находиться и внутри обособляемой конструкции. Поэтому со всех точек зрения запятую следует сохранить.

Answer (score 2):

Знаки препинания расставлены верно, здесь **независимая постановка запятой** (обособленное придаточное предложение) **и тире** (между подлежащим  и именной частью сказуемого, выраженными сущ. в И.п.).

Answer (score 0):

А попробуйте исходить из того, что если подлежащее и сказуемое разного рода (морфема - корень), то никакие вмешивающиеся конструкции не отменят тире.

А запятая - святое дело: закрывает придаточное.